# why does mypy `cast` only work some of the time?

Tags: python, mypy

First I made a silly little class

```
# cheese_helpers.py
class Cheese:
    pass
```

Then this happened

```
# weird.py

import lxml
from typing import cast, List
import cheese_helpers

o: List[Any] = []
reveal_type(o) # builtins.List[Any] as expected

y = cast(List[cheese_helpers.Cheese], o)  
reveal_type(y)  # builtins.List[cheese_helpers.Cheese], as expected

# so far so good. And then:

z = cast(List[lxml.html.HtmlElement], o)  
reveal_type(z) # builtins.List[Any] ???????????????
```

That last line should be `List[lxml.html.HtmlElement]` if you ask me. Cheese isn't annotated either and that works just fine.

I'm sure that to make the last line work I need to get/make some lxml annotations. But it seems very strange to me that my `cast` is being completely ignored. I cast to the Cheese class and it works. I cast to the HtmlElement class and it doesn't.

My question is why?

Comment: Quick check: what if you `import lxml.html` instead of just `import lxml`? Your current import appears to be incorrect; you need to explicitly import the submodule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps using an older version of mypy? When I try type-checking your code with both mypy 0.630 (the latest version on pypi) and the latest code on their git master branch, I get a revealed type of `builtins.list[Any]` in all three cases.

This revealed type is hopefully a little more intuitive -- the problem is that there are unfortunately no available stubs for the `lxml` library on [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed), which means that mypy has no information about what `html.HtmlElement` really is. (For all mypy knows, that could be a class, a function, a variable, a type alias, a namedtuple...)

So, it gives up and just assumes that it has a type of `Any`.

This also explains why assigning the output of `get_some_relevant_elements` to a `List[bool]` works without error. A variable of type `List[Any]` could theoretically contain anything, including bools -- so *maybe* this is a safe assignment.

---

In any case, if you don't like this behavior, your two options are to:

1. Accept that the `lxml` library has no type hints/is purely dynamically typed, and design your code so that all of that dynamism is contained in one location. As you extract information from your XML files, (optionally) validate them and return your own custom, annotated classes. Basically, deliberately contain a barrier between the dynamic and non-dynamic parts of your codebase.
2. Create your own stubs for lxml. These stubs don't necessarily need to be complex -- it might be sufficient to just create preliminary stubs for the few classes and methods that you need. (And if they do end up becoming fairly fleshed out, you could maybe open source them and contribute back to the community if you're so inclined.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it wasn't actually useful. I drastically changed my question to zoom in on the issue

Comment: @Sheena -- the gist of my answer still holds, even after your edit. There are no `lxml` stubs available, so mypy assumes anything you import from it is of type `Any`. In particular, the variable `lxml.html.HtmlElement` is assumed to be a type alias that's exactly equivalent to 'Any', not a class -- which is why the cast is a no-op. In contrast, if you add some file in your local project, mypy will analyze it + infer as much as it can from it, whether or not it happens to contain type annotations.

Comment: This decision to not analyze 3rd party libraries unless they explicitly opt-in to types is a deliberate one -- it's often the case that 3rd party libraries are written in a way that's very dynamic/will just end up confusing mypy. In this particular case, mypy *wouldn't* be able to analyze lxml even if it wanted to -- lxml is written in cython and distributed as a binary, and mypy doesn't have the ability to understand arbitrary binaries.